# Excel VBA - find charts name in range and set minumum axes value from range offset(0,1)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to do the following thing:

I have a sheet with 4 chart, the names of the graphs are: CHT_1, CHT_2, CHT_3, CHT_4.

In range ("u6;u9") I have the name of chart, In range("v6:v9") I have a value to ideally set the Minumum for every chart.

I would like a macro that find the name of chart in range("u6:u9") and set the minimum for this (every) chart for value find in range("v6:v9").

I tried this:

```
Sub SET_MIN_CHART()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyRange As Range

Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long
Set sh = Worksheets("Foglio1")
Dim cht As Chart
Set MyRange = Range("u6:W9")

If sh.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then

   For i = 1 To sh.ChartObjects.Count
   Set cht = sh.ChartObjects(i).Chart
   cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I've tried many other solutions, always worse. I thank so much everyone who can and wants to help me. Have a nice day to all of you, and thank you.

Dario

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you elaborate re "It doesn't work"? Does it error?

Comment: Thank you for welcome. Sorry for delay, but I was very busy. Solution for FunThomas works very well. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close.

Your loop should only run on the range holding the *names* of the chart. You can then access the value for the minimum of the axes from the cell next to the cell holding the chart name, you can use the `Offset`-function for that.

You can access the charts of a sheet either by index or by name. In your case, using the name comes handy.

Your code could look like this:

```
Sub SetMinChart()
    Dim cell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1")
        For Each cell In .Range("U6:U9")
            Dim chartName As String, minValue As Double
            chartName = cell.Value
            minValue = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            
            Dim co As ChartObject
            Set co = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set co = .ChartObjects(chartName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If co Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Chart " & chartName & " not found."
            Else
                co.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = minValue
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: FunThomas thank you so much, you really helped me. Have a great day. This evening I'll try your solution. Thank you again.

Comment: FunThomas your solution works very well. Thank you a lot, again. Have agreat day.